# How to write mathematic formula in python

Tags: python, math

I try to write these formulas in python but with no luck
[image]

I have no errors in code but I know that calculation gives incorrect result so I guess I have
 something wrong in implementation of formulas.

```
    import math
   lat = 54.5917455423
   lon = 17.2078876198
```

```
B = math.radians(lat)
L = math.radians(lon)
h = 55.889
pi = math.pi
a = 6378137
b = 6356752.3141
f = 1/298.257222101
ba = 1 - f# should be b/a = 1 - f

e = 0.006694380036
Da = 108
Df = - 4.80812 * 10 **-7
m = 0.000004848#one second in radians

dX = -23.74
dY = +123.83
dZ = +81.81
sin = math.sin
cos = math.cos
Rn = a/ math.sqrt(1-e**2 * math.sin(B)**2)
Rm = a*(1-e**2)/(1-e**2 * sin(B)**2)**(3/2)
vc = (Rm+h)*sin(m)

dB = (-dX*sin(B)*cos(L) - dY*sin(L) + dZ*cos(B) + Da*(Rn * e**2*sin(B)*cos(B)/a+Df)*(Rm*(a/b)+Rn*ba)*sin(B)*cos(B))*vc**-1
dL = (-dX * sin(L) + dY * cos(L) ) * ((Rn + h) * cos(B) * sin(m))**-1

a = dB * 180/pi + B
b = dL *180/pi + L

print a
print b
```

Comment: That's a broad statement. We need specific questions. What doesn't work? How does it go wrong? If you get an error, what's the error message?

Comment: What's the problem?  You realize that raising anything to the -1 power simply means that you should divide by it.  Provide a link explaining all this.

Comment: What is that formula about? so complicated...

Comment: Not that complicated.  Trig and algebra, little more.

Comment: This is geodetic calculation between BL coordinates on GRS-80 ellipsoid to BL coordinates on Krassovsky ellipsoid. In general, the result should be almost equal to B and L given.

Comment: That's great.  Post a link so we can check your work.

Comment: Is this sufficient, or is more needed?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRS_80

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't Python:

```
b/a = 1 - f
```

Comment: Yeah, but then how to write this in pythonic way?

Comment: It's not even valid code.  "b/a" is not valid variable name in any language I know.  Does this even compile?

Comment: @daikini Your problem here appears mathematical... What variable are you solving for (assuming two already have a value)? You need to isolate that variable on one side of the equation, just like you did in algebra class. In Python, that side happens to be the left.

Comment: While admirably succinct, would you mind expanding your answer just a little?

Answer (score 3):

This formula has errors in it:

```
dB = (-dX*sin(B)*cos(L) - dY*sin(L) + dZ*cos(B) 
    + Da*(Rn * e**2*sin(B)*cos(B)/a+Df)*(Rm*(a/b)+Rn*ba)*sin(B)*cos(B))*vc**-1
```

It should be:

```
dB = (  -dX*sin(B)*cos(L) - dY*sin(B)*sin(L) + dZ*cos(B)
        + Da*(Rn * e**2*sin(B)*cos(B)/a)
        + Df*(Rm*(a/b)+Rn*b/a)*sin(B)*cos(B)  )*vc**-1
```